MariaDB: Database connection failed with errno 2002 due to Resource temporarily unavailable
We are sporadically getting these errors for few milliseconds in PHP log on a busy web server.

2024/10/04 02:06:32 [error] 899410#899410: *566044078 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Database connection failed with errno 2002 due to Resource temporarily unavailable" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx, server: xxx.com, request: "POST /xxx.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9003", host: "xxx.com"

The server is a dedicated Debian 12 with 64 GB RAM. Allocated memory is ~19 GB.
MariaDB is version 11.3.2, PHP-FPM 8.3.12.
Despite setting log_warnings=4 in MariaDB configuration, there is absolutely nothing in the MariaDB log_error file at the time of issue. Also can't see any other obvious limits hit or increased traffic by watching the netdata graphs at that time.
Any idea how to find the root of the issue?

This question is similar to: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Resource temporarily unavailable - mysql - innodb and pdo. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The similar question is over 10 years old and related to MySQL (not MariaDB) database.

The issue was likely caused by the back_log variable which was set too low by default. Setting this variable to a higher value completely resolved the issue. So pity that MariaDB logs don't give a clue of it.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#back_log
